# Managing Hyper-V in a domain with RPC errors

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got an awkward setup here.

I've got a domain controller (2008 R2 STD) in the United States, and a Hyper-V 2008 R2 server (Raw Hyper-V server) and a Windows 7 workstation, all connected to a domain.

The Hyper-V server and the Windows 7 workstation are within the same network perimeter behind the same router.

So, all servers and clients can see each other. Good. However, I'm having trouble using the Hyper-V Manager from the client workstation to manage the Hyper-V server. I'm getting error:

```
You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Please contact the administrator of the authorisation policy for the computer "HYPERV-TEST".
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long shot, have you seen and followed this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee815290%28WS.10%29.aspx)  link on configuring it?

Answer (score 0):

We use a service account to manage our servers instead of our regular user accounts. So when you launch Hyper-V Manager you have to say "Run as Different User" and then enter in your service account credentials.